# Software for batch-watermarking photos?

Tags: lightroom, software, software-recommendation, watermark

I've been moving toward publishing my photos online and due to copyright concerns I want to put watermarks with my logo on my photos (mainly I just don't want people stealing my photos and claiming them as theirs when they aren't). Unfortunately, I can't find any modern software with the ability to watermark a batch (100+) photos at once (as lightroom CC removed watermarking).

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What copyright concern do you expect your logo to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the Linux way (assuming `imagemagick` is installed):

```
composite -dissolve 30% -gravity SouthEast -quality 100 logo.png in.jpg out.jpg
```

There is also [ImageMagick for Windows](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), I guess.

Here comes a quick explanation of the command:

`composite` - Command we execute, part of the IM suite
`-dissolve 30%` - Give the watermark an opacity of 30%
`-gravity SouthEast` - Locate watermark in bottom-right (possible values [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity))
`-quality 100` - Quite obvious, the JPEG quality for the output
`logo.png` - Your watermark, thanks to `-dissolve`, doesn't have to be opaque
`in.jpg` - The original image that you wish to watermark
`out.jpg` - The filename of the result image

Now let's write a quick bash script to watermark every image in the folder `originals`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in originals/*; do
    composite -dissolve 30% -gravity SouthEast -quality 100 logo.png "$i" "results/$(echo $i | cut -d '/' -f 2)"
done
```

Execute this in a folder containing your `logo.png` as watermark, a folder `originals` with your input images, and an empty folder called `results` where the modified images will be saved in.

Comment: If you do make the switch to Linux, look into [Darktable](https://www.darktable.org/about/features/) (basically lightroom but free), it has a watermark module too and even though I've never tried it I'm sure it can be applied in batch too!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Photoshop, you can record applying a watermark as a custom action, and apply that to a batch of photos (through File -> Automate -> Batch).

Alternatively, you can use a program like [JACo Watermark](http://jaco-watermark.sourceforge.net/) to process your files.

Comment: Can you provide your affiliation with the second software you mention?

Comment: I have no affiliation with it: it was the first open source, free-to-use software I found that was able to do what the OP asked for. (I realize the letters in the name are quite similar to my user name).

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom Classic CC still has watermarking features when you export the photos.  Adobe has the exact steps here: https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/using-watermark-editor.html

Comment: Came here to post exactly this!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with XNView MP software (free). Select the images, menu Tools->Batch Convert, on Actions tab select Add action->Image->Watermark, select appropriate image for watermark and press Convert button

Answer (score 1):

And my all-time favorite image viewer for windows, Irfan view.

**0. Backup your source material.**

1. File > Batch converion/rename.
2. On the panel choose Batch conversion and "Use advanced options.
3. And on the next panel there is the add watermark image, and adjust the position.

I would prepare a nice watermark in another program like Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

Faststone Image Viewer is another option. Free for non-commercial use and with a better interface than IrfanView and XNView.

Comment: Better interface for whom?

Answer (score 0):

I created [BatchWatermark.com](https://batchwatermark.com) to make it fast & convenient to watermark batches of photos. Give it a try. If it's missing anything, let me know and I'll do my best to address it.